# Showing a given parameterized contour is smooth

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Show that the range of the function $z(t) = t^3 +it^6$, $-1 \leq t \leq 1$ is a smooth curve, even though the given parameterization is not admissable.

I'm not entirely sure how to solve this problem, does any one have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the curve is the same as $z(u)=u+iu^2$ for $-1\le u\le1$.

Next notice that $z'(u)=1+2iu$ does not vanish for any $u\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: I understand the comment perfectly now. Sufficient to show $z'$ doesn't vanish because this statement in the form of vector calculus implies $Df \not = 0$ which we know from inverse function theorem means $f$ is a local diffeomorphism i.e $f'=Df$ is well-defined.  The connection is,  $$z=f=f(w) = f(x+iy) = f(x,y) = (u,v) = u+iv$$ I hope that makes sense. I've been re-learning complex analysis and its helped to realize that it agrees with vector calculus and extends due to the product structure. However there still is a difference between $f'$ and $z'$ again due to this structure difference.

Comment: I should be using $\sim$ instead of equality above. That was the reason for me being wrong the first time.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: Furthermore, the unit tangent to the curve is $\frac{z'}{|z'|}$ and this is smooth if $z'$ does not vanish.

Comment: Again, I understand everything you've said. I just made a hiccup due to the fact that I'm again re-learning the stuff.

Comment: So, maybe I'm misunderstanding. How is it that since the derivative doesn't vanish, the curve is smooth?

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that I recall my Prof mentioning that the integral of the derivative along that interval needs to be zero? I'm not entirely sure how this demonstrates that the curve is smooth.

Comment: @RyanGoulden: The derivative with respect to arclength is $\frac1{|z'(t)|}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$. The curvature vector is the second derivative with respect to arclength of the curve, so if $z'(t)$ is smooth and non-vanishing, then the curvature is smooth as well.